# How to download images and videos to local computer using the azure streaming manifest urls?

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

How to download images and videos to local computer using the streaming manifest urls generated from Azure media services?

OR How should i convert streaming manifest urls to MP4 or other media formats?

Answer (score 1):

If you encoded your content in Azure Media Services, they are already MP4 files in a container in Azure storage. You can list your assets, get the location in Azure Storage and then download the Mp4 files directly. 
You can also request what is called a "progressive download" URL for your MP4 files, which allows you to download the MP4 files directly from the origin (so long as you have not blocked that with a content protection policy.)

See the Azure Media Services Explorer tool for an example of generating Progressive download URLs, and also an easy way to explore the Media Services account.